# In shell, is there a way to run a default command when you just press enter without entering anything

Tags: bash, zsh, fish

I am thinking it would be cool to have some things run when you just press enter on command line without entering anything. It is kind of unusual thing to do so I am not sure where to look and how to even approach it.

Do you have any idea how I could do something like that? Maybe run something in prompt... but only when there is nothing entered.

Hope someone has an idea either yes or know. I personally use fish, but I would be curious in any of the mainstream shells, bash, zsh.

Thank you!

P.S. Alternatively, is there a way to make a facility like ctrl-R where you enter search string. Can you add a hook to ctrl-something?

Comment: The command processor doesn't really distinguish between commands separated by newlines and commands separated by semicolons, so would you want your default command to run multiple times in response to an input like `;;;;`?

Comment: (Ah, my comment does not apply to `fish`, and a similar workaround may be available in `bash`, `zsh`, etc.)

Comment: Ridiculous fish didn't explicitly address your final question but it too is solve using the `bind` command. For example, `bind \cr 'echo hello'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fish, you can do this by setting a custom binding for return, which modifies the command line if it's empty:

```
function replace_command
    string length --quiet (commandline)
    or commandline "echo hello world"
    commandline -f execute
end

bind \n replace_command
bind \r replace_command
```

This will run `echo hello world` if you press return with an empty command line.

(Look up `fish_user_key_bindings` if you aren't sure where the `bind` statements should go).

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can set either "PS1" or "PROMPT_COMMAND" shell variable to achieve what you want.

For example, I set `PS1` to this in my .bashrc to control my prompt:

```
export PS1='`date +%H:%M:%S` `echo $PWD | sed "s@$HOME@~@"` -> '
```

which displays the current time, followed by current directory (with the HOME portion taken off), and '-> '.

And when I hit return, it does update the time:

```
10:50:19 ~ -> cd /tmp    # cd changes the date & directory part in prompt
10:50:51 /tmp ->         # I just hit return key
10:50:52 /tmp ->         # Now the prompt shows updated date
```

Comment: This runs after *any* command, though, not just an empty command.

Comment: I agree with @chepner.  This doesn't check whether there was an empty command entered.

Comment: Now I just need to check if anything is entered...